# Levenshtein distance igonore overhanging bases

Tags: python, bioinformatics, levenshtein-distance

I would like an algorithm that reports that the edit distance between these two sequences is 2:

GCGGCTCCTCTGGGGCGTTCCC

GCGGCTCCTCTGGGGGGCGTTC

The first can be converted to the second with an insertion of 2 characters like so:

GCGGCTCCTCTGGGGGGCGTTCCC

GCGGCTCCTCTGGGGGGCGTTC

The lengths of the original two strings were 22.  The first 22 characters in these two strings are now identical.  The levenshtein distance between these two strings is 4, and I'd like a way of reporting an edit distance of 2 for these two strings.

Is there a way to do this with the python package Levenshtein_distance function or Levenshtein python package I'm already using?

More details:

I'm applying this to Next Generation Sequencing data.  I'd like to compare 2 sequences generated from a portion of each sequencing read.  The sequences are obtained from the start of the full length sequencing read and should be a unique sequence per sequencing read.

Example:
Read A: ATCGAACCGGTT
Read B: ATGAACCGGTT

Where the first four bases of the strings will be used as the unique identifier of each read.  Sequence ATCG is the unique identifier for Read A and ATGA is the unique identifier for Read B.  Both reads contain the identical sequence "AACCGGTT".  When comparing the unique identifiers (ATCG and ATGA), I'd like a metric that returns an edit distance of 1 between the two sequences.

Read A unique identifier:         ATCG
Read B unique id after insertion: AT_GA

The reasons I think the overhanging bases on the right side of the string (end of the sequencing) should not be penalized, but they should be penalized on the left side of the sequence, are as follows:

1. The first and most important reason is that just because there are overhanging characters on the right side of the string (AKA the end of the sequence), that doesn't mean the characters don't align between the two sequences being compared.  It only means we don't have the corresponding characters from the other sequence to compare them to.  The same is not true for the left side of the string.
2. Usually, the characters at the left side of the string (AKA the start of the sequencing read) are more confidently identified (have higher quality scores) than those on the right side.

Comment: The Levenshtein distance between these two strings is indeed 4, it's not clear what's the definition of "edit distance".

Comment: I don't see an easy way to do this with the standard Levenshtein function. However, I would try making a custom version of the function with one simple change; make the cost of deletions 0 instead of 1. I wouldn't trust it without robust testing though.

Comment: @hatchet Gotcya.

Your proposal to apply a 0 penalty to deletions is intriguing. I think it would have to include these rules:
1. Keep penalties of 1 per deletion in the middle of the string.
2.  Penalize deletions at end (right side) of string (of max length 2) with 0 penalty?
3. Can this number of allowed deletions be customizable?

Comment: Why is the right side special and not the left? Wouldn't you want GTG to TCG be a distance of 1 as well? GTG -> GTCG where the G on the left is a forgivable overhang.

Comment: I played around with the Lev function, but found it difficult to add the 0 cost for deletions without unwanted side effects. If your max distance is small (like in your example of 2), I think the most foolproof way is to use the existing Lev function with multiple calls that compare {stringA, stringA-lastchar, stringA-last2chars} against {stringB, stringB-lastchar, stringB-last2chars}. That would be 9 comparisons. A lot of extra processing, but should give exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not difficult to write a customized function to calculate the 'distance', you can try `edlib` first. Cause it is a very efficient tool to do this job.

Input Read A:

```
ATCGAACCGGTT
```

Input Read B:

```
ATGAACCGGTTATG
```

After Alignment:

```
ATCGAACCGGTT---   # these tailing gap will be ignored
AT-GAACCGGTTATG   # the internal gap is meaningful
```

*There is python tag in your question, so I post a solution using edlib python wrapper.*

```py
>>> import edlib
>>> edlib.align("ATCGAACCGGTT","ATGAACCGGTTATG", mode="SHW")['editDistance']
1
```

> `SHW` mode: gap at query end is not penalized

Comment: Thanks @Chang Ye this is almost perfect and may work for my purpose.  I just want to point out that the calculation depends on the order of the inputs.

```>>> edlib.align("ATGAACCGGTTATG","ATCGAACCGGTT", mode="SHW")['editDistance']

4

>>> edlib.align("ATCGAACCGGTT","ATGAACCGGTTATG", mode="SHW")['editDistance']

1```

Comment: Update: I had to install conda install -c bioconda python-edlib rather than conda install -c bioconda edlib in order to use edlib within python.  https://github.com/Martinsos/edlib/issues/102